# Index containing multiple fields in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

In MongoDB, How do i restrict the data entry bases on 3 fields RegisterUserId ,PageId and IsFavourite. None of them is unique?
what should the query be?

Below is my Schema

```
var FavMasterSchema = new Schema({
    FavUrl:String,
    RegisterUserId :  { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User',select: false},
    PageId:  { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId},
    IsFavourite: {type: Boolean,default:false}

});
module.exports = mongoose.model('t_FavMaster', FavMasterSchema);
```

Comment: I didn't get you!!! can explain it properly ??

Comment: How do i restrict the data entry bases on 3 fields RegisterUserId ,PageId and IsFavourite.
None of them is unique.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var FavMasterSchema = new Schema({
    FavUrl:String,
    RegisterUserId :  { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User',select: false},
    PageId:  { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId},
    IsFavourite: {type: Boolean,default:false}

});
```